# List Folder contents including all sub directories and files

Tags: java, list, file

Given folder structure:

```
FolderA
|_FolderB 
  |_FolderC
    |_File5
  |_FolderD
    |_File3
    |_File4
  |_File1 
  |_File2
```

I'm trying to write a small application that prints out all folder names, then all file names. The output should look like this:

```
FolderA
FolderB
FolderC
FolderD
File1
File2
File3
File4
File5
```

My attempt so far looks like this:

```
public class FileList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File rootFile = new File("FolderA");
        File[] files = rootFile.listFiles();
        
        System.out.println("Root file path: " + rootFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
        
        List<File> folderList = new LinkedList<File>();
        List<File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>();
        listFilesAndFolders(files, rootFile, folderList, fileList);
        
        extractFromList(folderList);
        extractFromList(fileList);
        
    }
    
    private static void listFilesAndFolders(File[] fList, File directoryName, List<File> folderList, List<File> fileList) {
        
        // Get all files from a directory.
        if(fList != null) {
            for (File file : fList) {      
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    fileList.add(file);
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    folderList.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static void extractFromList(List<File> list) {
        for (File item : list) {
            System.out.println(item.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it only prints out the direct contents of FolderA and not anf sub files or directories so I only get:

```
FolderB
FolderC
file2
file1
```

How do I change this so I get all sub files and folders?

Answer (score 3):

This is called walking a directory. There are readymade APIs available in Java. With NIO apis implementation looks like this:

```java
Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\temp")) 
            .filter(p -> Files.isDirectory(p)) 
            .forEach(System.out::println);

Files.walk(Paths.get("E:\\temp")) 
        .filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p)) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

`Files.walk(..)` returns stream of contents of the directory. Using [aggregate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) on the stream you can filter the contents.

There is also an [old way of walking the file tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have seen some nice example of how to use [`Files.walk`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-).

One alternative, that could also be considered, is Apache's infamous [commons-io](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io). From my observation, it is way faster, and even more customizable.

To list files recursively:

```java
FileUtils.listFiles(new File("\\path"), null, true)
        .forEach(System.out::println);

/*
  1. "null" can be changed with extensions array, like String[]{"jar", "txt"}, in order to filter file types that you want to list;
  2. "true" specifies, that you want a recursive search. "false" can also be used.
*/
```

To list directories recursively:

```java
FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(new File("\\path"),
        new NotFileFilter(TrueFileFilter.TRUE),
        DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You will need:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
</dependency>
```